# UIButton (inside UIView) in UITableViewCell click event not working

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

[image]

The above image is UITableViewCell designer preview. Button (Refer 1) touch up inside event is working properly.

But, Button (Refer 2) touch up inside event not triggering. It is inside  a view.

I disabled the UserInteractionEnabled property of Button(Refer 2)'s View.

But, No luck. Not working.

Comment: Have you checked by enabling the UserInteractionEnabled property of Button(Refer 2)'s View? @sriman reddy

Comment: yes. I checked. But still no luck

Comment: If button method not working then try to provide tap gesture to button that will also help you UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureRecognized:)];
        [yourbutton addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

Comment: check height of your view , set clips to bounds to yes, i have faced same issue , button is showing but not able to tap it because **view** is not same sized as cell

Comment: @PKT I set ClipsToBounds to yes. View became invisible.

Comment: ya because your view height is 0 set

Comment: you must set height of your view set it 30 for test

Comment: set background color red

Comment: @PKT Thanks a lot. I was striking my head on macbook for past 4 days. I set the height.  Its working now.

Comment: ya same happen with me i can see buttons but not able to touch it then i found issue so i can help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your View height is 0 that's why you not able to tap it

to test it set clips to bound value to yes

and also you need to set height for your view to solve that issue

Answer (score 2):

1) In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, assign button tag as index:

```
cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

2) Add target and action for your button as below:

```
[cell.yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

3) Code actions based on index as below in ViewControler:

```
-(void)yourButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
     if (sender.tag == 0) 
     {
         // Your code here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to trigger action on button in uitableviewcell, You have to make sure that you added its trigger event programatically because each and every button perform diff events for that row data according to indexpath.

So in CellforRowatindexpath just write below changes

1.) Set indexpath.row as button tag to that button

2.) Assign trigger event programatically to that button.

Its work fine...if u not cleared let me know i will help you to out.